# Next.js router not fetching query from url on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, next.js

So I have a React component called `[apiID].tsx` that looks like:

```js
import React from "react";
import { withRouter, NextRouter } from "next/router";

interface WithRouterProps {
    router: NextRouter;
}

interface MyComponentProps extends WithRouterProps {}
class DataPage extends React.Component<MyComponentProps, any> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            apiData: {},
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.fetchApi();
    }

    async fetchApi() {
        const apiUrl = `https://example.org/api/${this.props.router.query.apiID}?api_key=${process.env.API_KEY}`;
        const res = await fetch(apiUrl);
        const data = await res.json();
        this.setState({ apiData: data });
    }
}

export default withRouter(DataPage);
```

The page works fine when I click on a link that brings me to this page, but the problem occurs when refreshing the page. When I click on a link from another page that takes me here, the router successfully finds the query in the url and puts it into the `apiUrl` string. When refreshed, it returns undefined:

```
https://example.org/api/undefined?api_key=*******
```

I am new to both React and Next.js so I am not familiar with all of the ways that the router works. I tried putting the url in the state but that did not work either.

Comment: API_KEY is not a public variable. It should be `NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY`. This is because client-side, environment variable are injected at build-time. The NEXT_PUBLIC prefix is a security so you don't accidentally inject, say, your private Stripe API key into your client code. So this variable exists during SSR on the server but it is undefined client-side. I wrote an article with all possible patterns if you want more info: https://blog.vulcanjs.org/how-to-set-configuration-variables-in-next-js-a81505e43dad

Comment: Can't seem to replicate the issue, `this.props.router.query.apiID` is always set in `componentDidMount` when reloading the page. Could you provide a codesandbox highlighting the issue or similar?